How to have Blender to use the Python wheel that I provide in my extension?
How to have Blender to use the Python wheel that I provide in my extension?
The docs suggest that I can bundle all the dependencies of my extension inside the extension itself here.
I tried downloading the opencv-python-headless using pip download opencv-python-headless and it downloads all the dependencies of opencv as well which is numpy 2.1.3, I added these .whl files in a folder called wheels and added them to the manifest file, in my script I check for the version of these modules to make sure they work, like this:

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

def check_modules(self, context):
    try:
        message = f"NumPy : {np.__version__} \n OpenCV : {cv.__version__}"
    except ImportError:
        message = "3rd-party modules not found"

    self.report({'INFO'}, message)

and it is using the numpy that is bundle with Blender, I'm using Blender 4.2.0 and Numpy version is 1.24.3.
I was wondering, is there a way I can have this version of Numpy for just my extension while Blender uses it's own version of Numpy? or maybe if my extension can change the Blender's Numpy version?
Is there any way I can use the numpy version that works with the opencv version that I'm working with?

Oh no, not dependency paradox . Good luck, dev!
